# How to tell that an answer is from an enthusiastic user or from a spammer?

Tags: discussion, flagging, spam

I have [two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/125564/7454) [answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123362/7454) that are late answers, from the same 1-rep user (usually they are greedy enough to set their website to the project homepage, but not this one...), and that don't give much information about the product, but promoting it the same way. Is it enough to consider it as spam?

Comment: You could add "or a troll" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

90% likely to be spam.

Reasons:

- User not active otherwise.
- User has done nothing other than promote one commercial product. Big warning sign!
- Late answers imply a marketer was keyword-searching for forums / posts containing the word "KanBan" or "collaboration" or similar
- Not a particularly tailored answer, could easily be from a product brochure. Spammers are paid on quantity, not quality so you can expect cut & paste.

Answer (score 4):

The "answer" was:

> I think [KanbanTool][1] a quite good solution. It helps me to **organise teamwork**. I can use boards to **share and collaborate on work**. It has also a feature of **file sharing**.

The bold alone make be think it might be spam :) I've removed the bold for now.

Strikes against the user:

1. They are late answers.
2. They are **exactly** the same answer.

However, the answer is relevant and there's no indication on the users profile that this is his product. The answers were also posted several days apart.

I'm tempted to leave the answers for now, but if they get any (more) flags or attention I reserve the right to change my mind.

Comment: `They are exactly the same answer.` That's probably a byproduct of the questions. Both are closed, and rightly so, I don't think we should hold it against a new user that the questions survived long enough to generate quite a few answers. Bad questions almost always lead to bad answers. I think what's more alarming is that the later answer shows less effort than the first one.

Answer (score 4):

[One of the answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/what-kanban-specific-software-is-out-there/123362#123362) gives some information about the product (emphasis mine):

> I can recommend KanbanTool. You can **organize your work with colored sticky notes** placed on a kanban board to **visualize, control and optimize your workflow**. It also **provides analytics with breakdown charts and cumulative flow diagram**. You can also **invite people to build project teams and share online documents**.

That's quite a lot more information than some of the other answers to the [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/what-kanban-specific-software-is-out-there):

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/112479/25936
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123367/25936
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123366/25936
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/112474/25936
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/112475/25936

These are more spammy than cloue's answer. That's not to say that the answer is a good one, but I wouldn't go as far as calling it spam. It feels more like a fanboy / fangirl answer, the "I'm using this great thing and the world must know" type.

Some of the answers I linked to are from high reputation users, and some have quite a few upvotes, and that might have lead less experienced users to think it's ok to provide so poor answers.